# Load CKEDITOR in iframe doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ckeditor

I'm trying to load a full page into an iframe and replace a div with an CKEditor in that:

```
<body onload="fillframe();">
    <iframe id="edit-frame" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>
</body>
```

This is the function to fill the iframe with my page and replace some content inside:

```
$frame = document.getElementById("edit-frame");

function fillframe() {

    $win = $frame.contentWindow;
    $doc = $win.document;

    // fill iframe with page
    $doc.body.innerHTML = '<html><head>...</head><body><textarea id="editor"><h1>CONTENT</h1></textarea></body></html>';

    // load the ckeditor script:
    // CKEDITOR has to be loaded inside the
    // window it will be used in
    var script = $doc.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "ckeditor/ckeditor.js";
    $doc.head.appendChild(script);

    // try to replace textarea in iframe
    $win.CKEDITOR.replace("editor");

}
```

This works perfectly in chrome, but not in firefox. Firefox replaces the textarea inside my frame with the CKEDITOR, but CKEDITOR is completely disabled.The content inside of the textarea is not loaded in firefox:

[image]

But i can access it via console. `$win.CKEDITOR.instances.editor` for example returns me the whole CKEDITOR instance, where it says `status: loaded` inside the object.

Any ideas, what could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: CKEditor already makes an iframe. Why load it inside your own iframe?

Comment: It's part of a small CMS i'm working on. In the backend the whole frontend loads inside an iframe and the content area should be replaced by an CKEditor instance to let the user edit his website contents "directly on the frontend".

Comment: It's probably due to same-origin-policy: the std url of an iframe is `about:black`, which is a different `origin` than your website. Check the console (F12) for errors.

Comment: Unfortunately there's absolutely no error output in the console. I've logged all the callback functions. In chrome every callback returns it's event object. Firefox returns none of them. Only if i click on one of the buttons inside it, it returns an error, but i can't really get in the minified code. I'll try the latest uncompressed version from github now. Maybe i can find the error in the source by debugging several injection points.

Comment: Make sure it works in Firefox if you do the same thing without an iframe; load an identical HTML as the iframe into a FF window and check that at least that works, ruling out some general Firefox issue that is unrelated to the iframe.

Comment: Facing similar issue. Editor loaded disabled. What was the fix for it?

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't get it to work. Even if it worked in firefox, it didn't work in chrome, ie or safari. So i found another way to move the editor out of that iframe.